# Only one model working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this weird issue where only one of my models are actually working. The only model that's updating is "toDo" as it repeats underneath the form, but "clicked" nor 
"addToDo" are updating or being clicked:

using mvc

```
<head>
<title>ToDo</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Controllers/ToDoController.js"></script>
 </head>


<div class="container">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controll="myCtrl">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="toDoItem">To Do</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="toDoItem" placeholder="Enter your To-Do" ng-model="toDo"/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addToDo()">Add To Do</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>ToDo: {{toDo}}</p>
    <p>Clicked: {{clicked}} </p>

</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.toDo = "";
        $scope.clicked = false;
        $scope.toDoArray = {};

        $scope.addToDo = function() {
            scope.toDoArray.push($scope.toDo);
            $scope.clicked = true;
            alert("To Do Added");
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/npq5kc3h/

fiddle

Comment: Can you please share the code on js fiddle

Comment: $scope.toDoArray = {} is defind as literal object, change it to array and it might start working  $scope.toDoArray = [];

Comment: Its `ng-controller` not `ng-controll`.

Comment: @PunitaOjha https://jsfiddle.net/npq5kc3h/

Comment: @NiK648 amateur hour over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You have some issues

You have a typo in your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controll="myCtrl">
                              ^
```

You're not using the right `$scope` variable

```
scope.toDoArray.push($scope.toDo);
^
```

Your model `toDoArray` must be initialized as an array

```
$scope.toDoArray = {}; 
                   ^
```

**Snippet**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.toDo = "";
  $scope.clicked = false;
  $scope.toDoArray = [];

  $scope.addToDo = function() {
    $scope.toDoArray.push($scope.toDo);
    $scope.clicked = true;
    alert("To Do Added");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="toDoItem">To Do</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="toDoItem" placeholder="Enter your To-Do" ng-model="toDo" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addToDo()">Add To Do</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <p>ToDo: {{toDo}}</p>
    <p>Clicked: {{clicked}} </p>

  </div>
```